# Sharing files with Pythons SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: networking

Going to my directory and hitting

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

is really useful when I have to share files between two computers over my Wifi. I only have to look for my local IP address in ifconfig and there I go, without having to copy stuff to/from a USB drive.

But over the internet, it doesn't work with my public IP address even after opening port 8000 (the standard port for SimpleHTTPServer):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

It still doesn't work.

Might there be an issue with my Wifi router?

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to tell with certainty but I assume your local LAN is behind a router.  Your public IP adress is therefore the one of the router ... and the router has no SimpleHTTPServer.  So, if you really want to do that kind of manipulation, you have to instruct the router to redirect the port 8000 to your specific PC (local IP).  This is called 'PORT REDIRECTION'.
Instructions to do so vary from router to router and some IAP disallow this manipulation.  Be also aware that redirecting port to a specific adress need this adress to be knwon and stable.  So, probalbly you will have to configure the PC you are redirecting to, to have a static adress (instead of DHCP-allocated adress).

Be aware also that opening your PC to the Internet without protection is like opening your house (or at least one room) without any key or protection.  This means you are likely to meet there people you did not expect.